# Dependency Injection in .Net Framework using Microsoft.Owin and WebApi Routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to build basic Webapi using Microsoft.Owin on Console Application. Everything works well until Dependency Injection.

In this code, Owin and Webapi routing works well

```
private static void RunWebApi()
{
    const string baseAddress = "http://localhost:5000/";
    WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
}
```

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "1",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{value}",
            defaults: new { value = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

```
public interface ISingletonService
{
    string Id { get; }
}

public class SingletonService : ISingletonService
{
    public string Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
public class SettingsController: ApiController
{
    public SingletonService manager;

    public SettingsController(SingletonService manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
    }
    public SettingsController(){}
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage StartDeviceManager()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "value");
        response.Content = new StringContent("Hello", Encoding.Unicode);
        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
        };
        return response;
    }
}
```

I added this https://github.com/AxaGuilDEv/extensions-dependency-injection package to project and try to use it.
Implementation code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.DependencyResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(ServiceProviderConfig.ServiceProvider);
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "1",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: null
        );
        ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();
        appBuilder.UseScopedServiceProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider());
        appBuilder.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            var serviceScope = context.GetDependencyScope();
            var singletonService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISingletonService>();

            string message = $"singleton ID : {singletonService.Id}";

            context.Response.WriteAsync(message);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
    }
}
```

At this point, Dependency Injection works well but routing has no effect, I tried to add appBuilder.UseWebApi(config), but no response on any route.

Is there any way to use both of them in Microsoft.Owin(Katana)?

I am trying to build web api on .net framework Console Application. Routing and Dependency Injection does not working at same time. I am trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use your original map defaults in your first example, inside your second example? I notice the new config.Routes.MapHttpRoute defaults is "null"? Also, did you add the assembly type? It is now shown here. The AXA documentation has: [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AxaFrance.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Owin.Sample.Startup))]

Comment: When I test, I see this error on result, "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.". As I know routing is working, but injection does not.  I have also added OwinStartup, but I start WebApi using  WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);